# Border of XY coordinate region

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

In version 3.4.0, the XY coordinate area of the lightNew theme has no top and right borders.
I want to modify the border of the lightNew theme.But I didn't find the attribute I wanted in the 3.4.0 documentation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpze6.png)

I tried almost every attribute associated with "StrokeStyle".
Friends, I really hope to get your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are looking for is `seriesBackgroundStrokeStyle`

https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/chartxy.html#setseriesbackgroundstrokestyle

https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/interfaces/theme.html#seriesbackgroundstrokestyle